# Matplotlib incorrect display of data on the y-axis

Tags: matplotlib

Matplotlib incorrect display of data on the y-axis. Bars are displayed from coordinate 0.5 to 1.0, but this is not what I would like to see. Coordinates 1.0 are not in the data (`height` and `bottom`)

Code for example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

height = [0.5047, 0.4999, 0.4985, 0.4999, 0.4987]

bottom = [0.5002, 0.4969, 0.4956, 0.4969, 0.4967]

ax.set_ylim(0, 2)

ax.bar(x=x, height=height, width=0.2, bottom=bottom)

plt.show()
```

[see the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGegJ.png)

Comment: You bottom data is all ~0.5 and height data ~0.5. So, all bars look like they start at 0.5 and end at 1, which is correct. Give numbers that are further apart and you will see bars that are bigger/smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Matplotlib Pyplot Bars](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) use the

- **bottom** parameter to define the y-coordinate of the bottom of the bar
- **height** parameter to define the hight of the bar

Consequently, your bars start at `bottom` and end at `bottom+height`.

If you calculate the sum of each of coordinates, you will see that they all end roughly at about 1.0:
`print([sum(x) for x in zip(height, bottom)])` results in
`[1.0049000000000001, 0.9968, 0.9941, 0.9968]`

If you aim at drawing bars, whose y-coordinate start at bottom and end at height, then subtract them first

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
height = [0.5047, 0.4999, 0.4985, 0.4999, 0.4987]
bottom = [0.5002, 0.4969, 0.4956, 0.4969, 0.4967]

tmpHeight = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i - j, height, bottom))
ax.bar(x=x, height=tmpHeight , width=0.2, bottom=bottom)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, to get the height of the first bar I need to do 0.5047 minus 0.5002 and I get a height of 0.0045 and not 0.5047 as I wrote in the code